# javascript select variable in HTML script tag

Tags: javascript

Rookie question. (Possible duplicate?)

Can I directly select a variable (globalSurveyPackageData) in HTML script tag, as in the screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with select a variable?

Comment: Why would you post a screenshot of code? You can just copy and paste the code into the question...

Comment: You can drop the `var` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are available through out the page. So yours should be there to select.

```js
alert(myVar1);

alert(myVar2);

alert(myVar30);

alert(myVar400);
```

```html
<script>
    var myVar1 = 'one';
</script>

<script>
    var myVar2 = 2;
</script>

<script>
    var myVar30 = [10,20,30,40,50];
</script>

<script>
    var myVar400 = {
      one: myVar1,
      two: myVar2,
      three: function(){ return 3;}
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you are setting globalSurveyPackageData in the global scope.